# Local SQL Database not connecting

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, local

I'm trying to connect to a local SQL database for a (beginners) project I'm working on. I can't figure out how to connect to my local SQL database. I added the database to the project and when I test the connection I get no errors. Whenever I run my code (pressing button2) I get an error like this next to con.Open():

*"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"*

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ofd wordt gedeclareerd voor de "Open file dialog"
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();



  SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ImageDemoConnectionString);
```

But I pointed the database in my settings correct. I've also tried

```c#
Data Source = "Path\DB.sdf"
```

but it gives me the same error.

If anyone could give me a hint? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also, why is there a red mark next to the database name? http://oi46.tinypic.com/16kc09f.jpg

Comment: Whats is the connection string you have configured in your settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong connection type. An SDF file is a SQL Compact Edition database and needs to be connected with the [SqlCeConnection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983321.aspx). Also see, [Using SQL Server Compact (Visual Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983341.aspx) and [Connection strings for SQL Server Compact](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-ce).